# How to collect the 10 Google search results links (from which the class-attribute seems to have been dropped)?

Tags: javascript, xpath

I'd like to JavaScript-collect the (10 standard) result links returned in a standard Google search query. The following worked up until a few days ago:

`var noddy = content.document.evaluate('//h3/a[@class]', content.document, null, 7, null);`

Now it seems the `class` attribute of the anchor `<a>` tag has been dropped (for the standard results -- *"Results for Similar Searches"*, for instance, still works with the above line of code, as it (still) has its own `class` attribute in the anchor tag).

Any ideas (*apart from* `Greasemonkey`) how to collect those links anyway, e.g. by using the `class` of the encompassing "container" ?

Comment: `//h3[@class]/a` works a.t.m.

Comment: @Wrikken It does indeed ! (why ?)

Comment: Because all h3's have classes and contain an a?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do so by using this xpath

```
"//h3[@class='r']/a"
```

If you're using firefox, you can inspecting the elements using firebug. Notice the result links are under h3[@class='r']

Comment: Just to clarify: I don't see a way in `Firebug` to *directly* obtain the `xpath`; from `Firebug`, all you can do is "see" the basic `xpath` structure; but putting the correct `xpath` syntax together requires your own understanding / tinkering of and with the `xpath` syntax. Correctly observed?

Comment: in firebug, you can right click and copy xpath, however that won't be much readable, for example, the same copied xpath for the result links become this xpath: /html/body/div[6]/div[2]/div/div[7]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/ol/li/div/h3/a